# Propel to Doctrine Code Snippets

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, propel

This is a totally newbie question, so please bear with me. I am learning symfony from the online Jobeet and Askeet tutorials, but most of my hacks have involved Doctrine, so I am not familiar at all with Propel. I have managed so far by researching online and modifying to fit my needs, but I need a little help here.

Could someone give me a hand in translating these code snippets into Doctrine?

```php
public function setTag($v)
{
  parent::setTag($v);

  $this->setNormalizedTag(Tag::normalize($v));
}
```

```php
public function getTags()
{
  $c = new Criteria();
  $c->clearSelectColumns();
  $c->addSelectColumn(QuestionTagPeer::NORMALIZED_TAG);
  $c->add(QuestionTagPeer::QUESTION_ID, $this->getId());
  $c->setDistinct();
  $c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(QuestionTagPeer::NORMALIZED_TAG);

  $tags = array();
  $rs = QuestionTagPeer::doSelectRS($c);
  while ($rs->next())
  {
    $tags[] = $rs->getString(1);
  }

  return $tags;
}
```

```php
public function getPopularTags($max = 5)
{
  $tags = array();

  $con = Propel::getConnection();
  $query = '
    SELECT %s AS tag, COUNT(%s) AS count
    FROM %s
    WHERE %s = ?
    GROUP BY %s
    ORDER BY count DESC
  ';

  $query = sprintf($query,
    QuestionTagPeer::NORMALIZED_TAG,
    QuestionTagPeer::NORMALIZED_TAG,
    QuestionTagPeer::TABLE_NAME,
    QuestionTagPeer::QUESTION_ID,
    QuestionTagPeer::NORMALIZED_TAG
  );

  $stmt = $con->prepareStatement($query);
  $stmt->setInt(1, $this->getId());
  $stmt->setLimit($max);
  $rs = $stmt->executeQuery();
  while ($rs->next())
  {
    $tags[$rs->getString('tag')] = $rs->getInt('count');
  }

  return $tags;
}
```

```php
public static function getTagsForUserLike($user_id, $tag, $max = 10)
{
  $tags = array();

  $con = Propel::getConnection();
  $query = '
    SELECT DISTINCT %s AS tag
    FROM %s
    WHERE %s = ? AND %s LIKE ?
    ORDER BY %s
  ';

  $query = sprintf($query,
    QuestionTagPeer::TAG,
    QuestionTagPeer::TABLE_NAME,
    QuestionTagPeer::USER_ID,
    QuestionTagPeer::TAG,
    QuestionTagPeer::TAG
  );

  $stmt = $con->prepareStatement($query);
  $stmt->setInt(1, $user_id);
  $stmt->setString(2, $tag.'%');
  $stmt->setLimit($max);
  $rs = $stmt->executeQuery();
  while ($rs->next())
  {
    $tags[] = $rs->getString('tag');
  }

  return $tags;
}
```

Comment: from where did you get this code?

Comment: http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to forget Askeet tutorial, it is for the 1.0 release, and lots of things change since this version.

But, you can find a [svn dump](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/t/11385/) of a doctrine version of Askeet. You should use SVN to rebuild the repo (don't know how to perform that).

On an other hand, if you need to handle tag in sf1.4 project, I recommend you to use the plugin [sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin/trunk).

Comment: Thanks for the svn tip. Didn't know it existed. I currently have sfDoctrineActAsTaggable installed on another project. It seems like a very potent plugin. It created 2 tables in my scheme: tag & tagged. Neither of them references te user that submit the tag. How Important is it, conceptually speaking, to attribute tag entries to user and save that relationship in the database?

Comment: How important is it ? It really depends on your project. I have one using tag and I don't need to know who add a tag. But if you want to add this feature, you will have to rewrite/extend current plugin.